# Are there ionic solids that conduct electricity?

Tags: ionic-compounds, electricity

We are taught in school that ionic substances don't conduct electricity, and when they do, it is either because they are in a molten state or because they are in solution. I understand these concepts.

Are there any exceptions? By exceptions, I am looking for ionic compounds that may not conduct electricity well, but they conduct electricity better in comparison to other ionic compounds. Additionally, what makes such a compound a better conductor of electricity?

Comment: Mentioning that you are looking for ionic substances that conduct electricty in 'their solid state' would make the question more clear. The standalone statement that _ionic substances don't conduct electricity_ is false as (like you mentioned) their molten state (which still is the same substance) conducts electricity.

Comment: Does not fit perfectly into your question but you can have molecules and macromolecules whose ions - often present in pending groups - have mobility, or at least leads to electrons / hole with mobility. Example of the first case is PEDOT, examples of the second kind are the Os of OLEDs.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/what-makes-ionic-conduction-fast-or-slow https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26863/what-is-the-meaning-of-superionic

Comment: Yes there are  - take a look at the second paragraph in the answer to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67481/does-aluminium-oxide-ionize-after-melting-point/67493#67493

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, there are.**

Ionic conductivity greatly varies between compounds. For some of them is *much* higher then for others. They are called [**fast ion conductors**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_ion_conductor), or **superionic conductors**.

Well known example is [silver iodide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_iodide). While it may be called a "salt", it's probably more covalent then ionic, that is, before it's heated to 146 °C, when its structure changes and Ag ions are "set loose" to conduct electricity. In result conductance rises a few *thousand* times.

If rubidium iodide is added to $\ce{AgI}$ we can get [rubidium silver iodide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubidium_silver_iodide) which is even better, and is sometimes classified as one of "advanced" superionic conductors.

Many substances can be superionic in right circumstances, even [water ice](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115429/what-would-superionic-water-ice-look-like) can, if temperature and pressure are high enough.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**.

Another example is [VO2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanadium%28IV%29_oxide). Over 67 °C its crystal structure changes to rutile with a band gap of ~0.1 eV. Dopants of other substances can reduce the temperature at which it becomes a conductor.

Comment: It's arguable if it is actually ionic. While oxides of transition metals are typically treated as such, it's a drastic simplification. VO2 conducts via electrons not ions.